# Create a channel in the same category from the sent textcannel

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm try to create a `Textchannel` in the same category where it come from.

```
[Command("createTextChannel")]
public async Task Create_TextChannel(string nameofChannel)
{
   var vChan = await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync(nameofChannel);

   var categoryID = //CategoryID from sended Cannel
   await vChan.ModifyAsync(prop => prop.CategoryId = categoryID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create the channel and then modify it to include the category. Just specify the category during creation.

```cs
await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync(name, x =>
{
    x.CategoryId = (Context.Channel as ITextChannel).CategoryId;
});
```

Comment: `Context.Channel.CategoryId` is `CategoryId` red underlined. CS1061: 'ISocketMessageChannel' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryId'

Comment: Updated the response. Try casting the channel as a `TextChannel` to access the `CategoryId`